# The height of right isosceles triangle decreases with the speed proportional to the area of this triangle

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

The height of right isosceles triangle decreases with the speed proportional to the area of this triangle. At time $t=0$ the area of triangle is $2$, and at time $t=1$ the area of triangle is $\frac12$. What is the area of triangle at time $t=3$? The answer is given as $\frac18$, but I do not know how to write down the appropriate formula for the general case.

It looks like the main idea is the derivative, and should be the ratio of change in area during the time one second? Can somebody help and describe the general case in terms of functions and how to tackle similar problems?

Comment: Area $S=h^2$, so $h'=-kS$ is a differential equation. This yields $h=\frac{1}{C+kt}$, we plug $h(0)=\sqrt{2}$ and $h(1)=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$ to obtain $k,\,C$ and then we plug $t=3$.

Comment: "The hight of right isosceles triangle decreases with the speed proportional to the area of this triangle." This is **dead wrong**.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter: That statement is wrong in general, but the problem says that is happening in this particular case. Perhaps you are thinking of when the height has a constant rate of decrease, but that is not what is happening here.

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin: That is a good answer. Why don't you write it as a full answer, so I can upvote it?

Comment: Thanks. I'm not sure I can explain all the reasoning clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

The height $h$ splits the triangle into $2$ right-angled triangles, with area $\frac{1}{2}h^2$ each (this height is a median also, which length is equal to $\frac{1}{2}$ of hypotenuse's). Thus area $S=h^2$.
Let $h(t)$ be the function of dependance $h$ of $t$. Then the speed is given $h'_t=\frac{dh}{dt}$. It's proportional to area $S$: $h'=kS$ is a differential equation
$$\frac{dh}{dt}=kh^2$$
$$\frac{dh}{h^2}=k\,dt$$
$$\int\frac{dh}{h^2}=\int k\,dt$$
$$-\frac{1}{h}=kt+C$$
$$h=-\frac{1}{kt+C}$$
Now we plug $h(0)=\sqrt{2}$ and $h(1)=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$:
$$\begin{cases}
-\frac{1}{C}=\sqrt{2}\\
-\frac{1}{k+C}=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}
\end{cases}$$
$$\begin{cases}
C=-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\\
k+C=-\sqrt{2}
\end{cases}$$
$$k=-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$$
Thus, $h(t)=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{t+1}$ and $h(3)=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{4}$.